# regex: check if two phone numbers differ at most by 1 number

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset of phone numbers that I want to check against each other. Basically the regex should throw a match if two phone numbers are at most 1 digit apart. For example, we have the following phone numbers:

- +31612345678
- +31612245678

These numbers are the same apart from position number 7 (first number has a 3 while the second number has a 2). As these phone number differ by 1 digit, the regex should throw a match. It stands to reason that the regex should also throw a match if the phone numbers are exactly the same. In the following case (see below), the regex should however not throw at match as the phone numbers differ by more than 1 digit:

- +31612345678
- +31611145678

Does anyone have a good regex in mind? I am writing the regex using the re module in python.

Comment: This is nothing that a regex is well suited for

Comment: Any reason why you're trying to use regular expressions? Also, please show what you've tried already.

Comment: Seems that there is no simpler way. regex is not thing for comparison , as mentioned by @FranciscoCouzo show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use case - if you want to also catch "oh, you missed a digit" or "eh, that digit shouldn't have been there", use the edit distance between the two numbers instead.

You can use the levenshtein edit distance to get a number for how many "edits" would be required between two numbers, for example by using the [editdistance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance) library for python.

```
>>> import editdistance
>>> editdistance.eval('banana', 'bahama')
2L
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best code, but it would do the job.

```
from collections import Counter
a = '+31612345678'
b = '+31612245678'

def match(p1, p2):
    ct = Counter([a == b for a, b in zip(p1, p2)])
    if not ct[False] > 1:
        <throw match>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use a regular expression for this. If your phone numbers have the same length something simple as

```
def is_match(phone_nr_1, phone_nr_2):
    diff = filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1],
                  zip(phone_nr_1, phone_nr_2))

    return len(diff) <= 1

print is_match("+31612345678", "+31612245678")
#=> True

print is_match("+31612345678", "+31611145678")
#=> False
```

would do the job.